# Transcoding pixel data of bitmap from android to IOs through sockets create blue layer on bimap on IOs

Tags: android, ios, iphone, image-processing, bitmap

I am developing an app in which i need to send the bitmaps in the form of pixel data from android to ios through sockets to preview the android bitmaps.I send the pixel data from android successfully but when i convert the pixel data to bitmap image in IOS the resulting image display with the blue layer on it.

Following is my code of android.

```
int[] pixels = new int[scaledBitmap.getHeight() * scaledBitmap.getWidth()];
scaledBitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), 0,
                    0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight());
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(pixels.length * 4);
IntBuffer intBuffer = byteBuffer.asIntBuffer();
intBuffer.put(pixels);
byte[] imagedata = byteBuffer.array();
osRC.write(imagedata ); // osRC outputstream of destination IOS socket.
```

Following is the code on IOS Side that receive the buffer

```
(UIImage ) createUIImage: (char) buffer :(int)width :(int)height
{  
CGColorSpaceRef rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = nil;
context = CGBitmapContextCreate(buffer, width, height, 8, width * 4,rgbColorSpace,kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);//kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little

// create image from data in graphics context
CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
CGColorSpaceRelease(rgbColorSpace);
CGContextRelease(context);
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage];
CGImageRelease(newImage);
return image;
}
```

I also try this with different color spaces on android and also by changing the color channels of RGB and ARGB. But after these changes I suffer the same problem that the resulting image on ios displays but with some color layer and most of the time this layer is blue.

I have also tried to convert the pixel data on android with the following code.

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytesperRow * height);
scaledBitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer);
byte[] imagedata = byteBuffer.array();
osRC.write(imagedata ); // osRC outputstream of destination IOS socket.
```

I hope this made clear what I'm trying to do.i need to know what should i do to get the pixel data from android to send it to ios so that ios display the same bitmap as in android.

Your help will be much appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why aren't you sending a PNG instead? Less headaches and probably less bandwidth due to compression, too.

Comment: BTW, method names like `createUIImage:::` (no names for the second and third parameters) are discouraged. Better name use something like `createUIImageWithBuffer:(const *char)buffer width:(int)width height:(int)height`.

Comment: And is it a typo that your signature is `createUIImage: (char) buffer` (notice the `char`) instead of `char *` or better yet `const char*`? You should get a compiler warning at `CGBitmapContextCreate` and possibly a crash…

Comment: Thanks for your urgent reply. But I've tried image formats i.e JPEG and PNG. But this also do the same behavior on ios.

Comment: You mean, when you transmit a PNG and you're using [`+[UIImage imageWithData:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithData:) to read it you still get a blue image? Than the problem must be on Android's side.